# Transforming data from Pandas dataframe to time series training data for keras LSTM

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm using Keras along with Hyperas to with with an LSTM machine on predicting valuations for prices. I'm having problems with formatting my data from the Pandas DataFrame to use for training and testing data in the LSTM model.

This is how I read and split the data at the moment:

```
def data():
    maxlen = 100
    max_features = 20000
    #read the data
    df = DataFrame(pd.read_json('eth_usd_polo.json'))

    #normalize data
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))
    df[['weightedAverage']] = scaler.fit_transform(df[['weightedAverage']])
    X = df[df.columns[-1:]]
    Y = df['weightedAverage']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y , test_size=0.33)


    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, max_features, maxlen
```

From the dataframe I'm really only interested in the "weightedAverage" column and it's corresponding prices. Since I'm doing a univariate time series forecasting.

And this is where I build the model:

```
def create_model(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, max_features, maxlen):
    #Build the model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(input_shape=(10, 1), return_sequences=True, units=20))
    model.add(Dropout(1))
    model.add(LSTM(20, return_sequences=False))
    #model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(units=1))
    #model.add(Activation("linear"))

    #compile
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'],
                  optimizer={{choice(['rmsprop', 'adam', 'sgd'])}})

    #the monitor and earlystopping for the model training
    #monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor ='val_loss', patience=5,verbose=1, mode='auto')

    #fit everything together
    #model.fit(x_train ,y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), callbacks =[monitor], verbose=2, epochs=1000)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train,
        batch_size={{choice([64, 128])}},
        epochs=1,
        verbose=2,
        validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

    score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)

    print('Test accuracy:', acc)
    return {'loss': -acc, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'model': model}
```

The problems seems to arise in how I extract and handle the data from the Pandas DF. The returning data (X_train, X_test etc) should be in the form of:

```
(25000, 10)
[[ data data data .... data data]
 [ data data data .... data data]
.
.
.
[ data data data .... data data]]
```

Instead it's formatted to:

```
   (7580, 1)
        weightedAverage
12420       255.151685
20094       871.386896
12099       300.802114
```

I thought the `train_test_split` function would help me in splitting and formatting my data to the correct size, but it doesn't seem to do what I want from it.

Any help is greatly appreciated with this!

Comment: Your `X = df[df.columns[-1:]]` is the last column of df and hence it should be of shape(size, 1), where as the `Y = df['weightedAverage']` also seem to be of similar shape(size,1), So how are you expecting the shape out of train_test_split to be different from shape(something, 1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling and trial and error I got it working.
Now the data is beautifully formatted for my LSTM machine and it's working great.

It can now also handle multivariate inputs which I'm hoping will improve the quality of predictions.

```
def data():
    maxlen = 10
    steps = 10
    #read the data
    print('Loading data...')
    df = (pd.read_json('eth_usd_polo.json'))
    df = df.drop('date', axis=1)
    #normalize data
    scalerList = []
    for head in df.dtypes.index:
        scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))
        df[[head]] = scaler.fit_transform(df[[head]])

        scalerList.append(scaler)
    Xtemp = np.array(df)
    X = np.zeros((len(Xtemp)-maxlen-steps,maxlen,len(Xtemp[0])))
    Y = np.zeros((len(X),steps))
    for i in range(0, len(X)):
        for j in range(steps):
            Y[i][j] = Xtemp[maxlen+i+j][6]

        for j in range(len(X[0])):
            for k in range(len(X[0][0])):
                X[i][len(X[0])-1-j][k] = Xtemp[maxlen+i-j-1][k]
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y , test_size=0.33, shuffle=True)    
    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, maxlen, steps
```